# UnexpectedStatusException: Error for Training job sagemaker-scikit-learnxxxx Failed. Reason: AlgorithmError: framework error

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am quite fustrated by AWS training. It always stuck at the point when I am training my model giving the above error ...AlgorithmError: framework error

What is the error about ? i am using framework : '0.23-1" and RandomForestClassifier?

Does this mean that RandomForestClassifier is not found there

REgards

Comment: were you able to resolve this? I am running into a similar issue with using the random forest classifier in script mode

Comment: @nehatj : hi I found out my problems was due to me running on AWS services in different region and there is some naming change

Answer (score -1):

This is the problem with my AWS

`UnexpectedStatusException: Error for Training job sagemaker-scikit-learn-2021-10-01-05-40-37-991: Failed. Reason: AlgorithmError: framework error:`   ...

This is my solution

You might want to check some naming change in the following : parser.add_argument('--data-dir', type=str, default=os.environ['SM_CHANNEL_TRAIN'])" .... parameter got changed for me to SM_CHANNEL_TRAINING

Regards